# Execute NetCoreApp installed in global nuget cache

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

I have installed successfully a Nuget package containing a .Net Core console based app including all dependencies.

But, I have not found a way how to execute the console app.

dotnet Path\App.dll does not seem to handle dependencies...

Thanks for ideas!

/iP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't create the package, then the best suggestion I can offer is to download the app's dependencies in the same way you downloaded the app's package, then copy all the dlls into a single folder. Not easy or fun, but NuGet was never designed to be an application distribution system.

If you did create the package, you should read these docs on [dotnet global tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools), and this page on [creating a global tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create). That will provide a way to easily install and run a package containing a command line program.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for:).